# UTF8 encoding of a subject line in a MIME email for NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mime-mail

I cannot understand what's going on here. I received an email w/the following UTF8 encoded subject line and I'm unable to convert it to the below encoding.

Unconverted:
Переход на прямые договоры узаконен!

Converted:
=?UTF-8?B?0J/QtdGA0LXRhdC+0LQg0L3QsCDQv9GA0Y/QvNGL0LUg?= =?UTF-8?B?0LTQvtCz0L7QstC+0YDRiyDRg9C30LDQutC+0L3QtdC9IQ==?=

Could you help me understand what is going on here? What is the MIME encoding above exactly? A conversion to a UTF8 string don't match what I see above.

Comment: NodeJS package to encode - https://www.npmjs.com/package/libmime

Comment: The above encoding appears to be chunked as well ... I can't figure out the max value however.

Answer (score 0):

Those characters are not covered with ascii and encoded in UTF-8. Moreover, the email subject MIME encoding was done using UTF-8 (RFC2047).

Easiest solution for this is, using [npm rfc2047 library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rfc2047). Refer the sample code below.

```
const rfc2047 = require('rfc2047');
let subjectLine = "=?UTF-8?Q?Votre_demande_de?=\n =?UTF-8?Q?_a_=C3=A9t=C3=A9_approuv=C3=A9e!?=";
let frenchSubjectLine = rfc2047.decode(subjectLine);
console.log("FR subject line after decoding: [" + frenchSubjectLine + "]");
```

Output is

```
FR subject line after decoding: [Votre demande de a été approuvée!]
```